# Memory Editing in Python. Delete Last Node in LinkedList

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-management

From Cracking the Coding Interview. Task 2.3.

You have linked list and you need to make a function that accepts only node from that list and removes it from that list.

When the node is in the middle, it's simple. you just reassign fields `value` and `next` to next node in the list. But how to get rid of the last node in the list?

I was looking for a way to modify memory in Python, but couldn't find any that actually works. Can anybody suggest anything?

Here is the code:

```
class LinkedListNode:
    def __init__(self, item, next = None):
        self.item = item
        self.next = next


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__head = None

    def append(self, item):
        self.__head = LinkedListNode(item, self.__head)

    @property
    def head(self):
        return self.__head

def remove_node(node):
    if node.next:
        next = node.next
        node.item = next.item
        node.next = next.next
        next.next = None
    else:
        # WHAT TO DO HERE?
        pass
```

Comment: If node.next.next is None then node.next = None, ins't as simple as that?

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to write a function, rather than a method for your linked list class? Are you sure your linked list is supposed to be singly-linked?

Comment: node.next is None already, cause it's the last node in list. Yes, function, cause you only have a node, not the whole list, that's my question. Imagine a situation, where you only receive the last node of the list. In C++ you modify the value by memory address. How to do the same in Python?

Comment: `remove_node` isn't removing the node; it's removing the node *after* the given node. If there is no such node, there's nothing to do; you can just return.

Comment: You couldn't do this in C++ either.

Comment: @chepner: It's removing the next node and rewriting the current node's attributes to look like the removed node, so it looks like it's removing the current node. That doesn't work with the tail.

Comment: @user2357112 It has finally got to me, after playing around in c++ implementation. Don't matter what I do with the node memory, in order to do what I requested I need to change pointer of the previous element to point to 0x0 or NULL address. Putting all bytes of the last node to '0' won't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with C++ implementation I realized the following.

Imagine, you have list of 3 elements: 3 -> 2 -> 1.

We want to remove last node that contains value `1`. If we take C++ code and check what is happening with our elements we will see what's stored in nodes `3`, `2` and `1`:

```
3: 48416413-411270030000000
2: 32416413-411270020000000
1: 0000000010000000
```

We can see that each node has a `next` pointer and a `data` value. And last node has a `next` pointer. So, in order to do what I wanted, we need to get previous to last node and set it's pointer to 0x0 (NULL pointer). That means that either on C++ or on Python current implementation is impossible, unless there is a way to find pointer to memory slot.

See C++ implementation below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
    public:
    Node* next;
    int data;
};

class List
{
    private:
    Node *head;

    public:
    List()
    {
        head = NULL;
    }

    Node* get_head() { return head; }

    void append(int val) {
        Node* newHead = new Node();
        newHead->data = val;
        newHead->next = head;
        head = newHead;
    }
}

int main() {
    List* list = new List();
    list->append(1);
    list->append(2);
    list->append(3);

    cout << "List: " << list->str() << "\n";

    Node* node = list->get_head();
    while (node) {
        cout << node->data << ": ";
        string str(reinterpret_cast<char*>(node), sizeof(*node));
        for(string::iterator it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it) {
            int i = *it;
            cout << i;
        }
        cout << "\n";

        node = node->next;
    }

    cout << "List: " << list->str() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```